# Java EE 6: Target Unreachable, identifier 'helloBean' resolved to null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6, managed-bean

I am trying to get a simple JSF 2 tutorial example to work.

I am using the dynamic web project in Eclipse and publishing to a Glassfish 3 server (run -> run on server). The first index.xhtml page loads correctly, but when I have to access a managed bean, the following error displays:

```
/index.xhtml @14,48 value="#{helloBean.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'helloBean' resolved to null
```

I've had a look at the various other discussions on this topic, however the solutions never seem to work for me (e.g. adding beans.xml, giving the managed bean a name etc, following naming conventions).

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

Index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h3>
        <h:form>
           <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
           <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="response"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

response.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body bgcolor="white">
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - welcome.xhtml</h3>
        <h4>Welcome #{helloBean.name}</h4>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Managed bean:

```
package java.hello1;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name = "Ricardo";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

  <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: If you are running your code using maven, try run it with maven goal `tomcat:run-war` instead of `tomcat:run`. Hope this help. :)

Comment: @stiv: then you've not the same problem as the OP. Have you copy'n'paste'n'runned his code in a completely blank playground project with everything set to default?

Comment: I've created project with Intellij IDEA, added support for JSF, but it doesn't want to see my bean. At the same time <h: tags are executed correctly.

Comment: @stiv: if you used **exactly** the same code and environment setup (Eclipse + Glassfish 3) then I don't see other causes to the problem than already answered. Conclusion is then that you don't have **exactly** the same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 14):

You need to have a JSF 2.0 compliant `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file in order to get JSF to interpret the annotations.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Config here. Can even be kept empty. -->

</faces-config>
```

If you already have one or if that doesn't solve the problem, please pay attention to server startup logs if you don't see any warnings/errors.

By the way, your `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file is declared conform Servlet 2.5 specification. While this may not necessarily harm, it makes no sense if you're using a Servlet 3.0 compliant container. Update the root declaration as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

The `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` is intented for CDI annotations like `@Named`, `@Inject` and so on. Just a completely empty file is sufficient to turn it on. It has totally no relationship to JSF annotations like `@ManagedBean`, `@ManagedProperty` and so on. It should also not be confused/mixed with each other.

Answer (score 10):

I've been stuck with such a problem for half a day. The problem in my case appears only when I do run the WebApp from Eclipse. JSF 2 looks in WEB-INF/classes for annotated beans and doesn't find them.  To solve this I've changed build output path to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes. Here is detailed explanation of similar case: [Jetty maven goal jetty:run does not work with JSF 2.0 @ManagedBean](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288243)

Comment: This is the fault of the build tool and/or the server plugin. Eclipse in its default trim (without Maven or any custom server plugins) does the job rightly.

Comment: for anyone trying mkyong example (as it is in 2015) http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ that is the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

In the exact same scenario as OP (with eclipse, publishing to a Glassfish 3 server using run -> run on server) I get exactly the same error until removing spaces from the eclipse Project Name. Simply removing any spaces solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i tried everything. After that, i just clicked "Click and Build Project" button, "Build Project" button and resarted GlassFish server. After, it works to me, for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please you check your war file and see if your classes are under WEB-INF/classes folder.
I ran into the same problem and found out there are no class files WEB-INF/classes folder.

Answer (score -1):

Include @Named in your Controller/Bean..

Comment: This is indeed one of possible answers to the problem as described in the question title, but this does not answer the problem as described in the question body itself.

Comment: I got the error when I used Named annotation on my hello bean. It got resolved by using @ManagedBean annotation.