# Trying to use CDI on Glassfish 4 results in javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'indexMB' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, cdi

I am getting an error on a single page, and the only error occurs after I click the SUBMIT button.

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'indexMB' resolved to null

I followed the recommendations of the topic [JSF2 form submit " Target Unreachable, identifier 'myModel' resolved to null ONLY on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273731/jsf2-form-submit-target-unreachable-identifier-mymodel-resolved-to-null-onl) but did not help me.

Any help will be very useful.

Follow my setup and my files:

- Glassfish 4
- Primefaces 3.5
- commons-fileupload 1.3
- commons-io 2.4

`index.xhtml`

```
<f:loadBundle basename="i18n" var="bundle" />
<h:head>
    <title>#{bundle['index_title']}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    #{bundle['index_appname']}
    <br />
    <h:form id="frmIndex">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="user" value="#{bundle['lblUser']}" />
            <p:inputText id="user" value="#{indexMB.user}" />

            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="#{bundle['lblPassword']}" />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{indexMB.password}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton action="#{indexMB.loginTest}" value="#{bundle['btn_login']}" />
    </h:form> 
</h:body>
```

`IndexMB.java`

```
@ManagedBean ("indexMB")
@RequestScoped
public class IndexMB {

private String password;
private String user;

public IndexMB() {
}

public String loginTest(){
   ...
}

// getters and setters
}
```

log (Glassfish)

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @18,66 value="#{indexMB.user}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'indexMB' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findConverter(InputRenderer.java:190)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:196)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'indexMB' resolved to null
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:174)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:86)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    ... 43 more
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

`faces-config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

`beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere CDI really comes into play here. That notwithstanding, where are you importing `@ManagedBean` and `@RequestScoped` bean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bean is really not a CDI bean I guess your problem is caused by mixing up the imports. So try

```
 @javax.inject.Named //defaults to "indexMB"
 @javax.enteprise.context.RequestScoped
 public class IndexMB {
      //rest of your class here
 }
```

Comment: I changed "@ManagedBean" by "@Named" and it worked. Thanks!