# Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null - JSF

Tags: jsf, tomcat6, jsf-2.2

Problem similar to:
[Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322762/target-unreachable-identifier-resolved-to-null-jsf-2-2)
[How to reference JSF managed beans which are provided in a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663818/how-to-reference-jsf-managed-beans-which-are-provided-in-a-jar-file/7663898#7663898)
[Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)
[Java EE 6: Target Unreachable, identifier 'helloBean' resolved to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809511/java-ee-6-target-unreachable-identifier-hellobean-resolved-to-null)

But none of resolutions helped me. When I click command button (on page, please see xhtml file) I got:

```
An Error Occurred:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /navigate.xhtml @15,90 action="#{navigator.choosePage}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'navigator' resolved to null
```

I can get why. Why this bean is not visible in jsf?

Using java8, j2ee 7, tomcat 6.0.44

My pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>jsfTut</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- JSF deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<display-name>JSF</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSF</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSF</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSF</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
</faces-config>
```

Simple class:

```
package pl.sarseth.jsf;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "navigator")
public class Navigator {

    public String choosePage(){
        if(Math.random() > 0.5){
            return "result-page-1";
        } else {
            return "result-page-2";
        }
    }
}
```

And xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>My JSF page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Navigate via Java</h1>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Use Java to Navigate to Results Page</legend>
        <h:form>
            Press button to get one of two possible results pages.<br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Go to Random Page" action="#{navigator.choosePage}"/>
        </h:form>
    </fieldset>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Project structure is this:

```
project
---src
   ---main
      ---java
         ---pl.sarseth.jsf
            ---Navigator.java
      ---webapp
         ---WEB-INF
            ---faces-config.xml
            ---web.xml
         ---index.xhtml
         ---navigate.xhtml
 ---pom.xml
```

Comment: why isn't Navigator class scoped?

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar sessionScoped? Tried with that. No difference there. ViewScoped tried as well. Do not understand those scoped, but tred them with bruteforce.

Comment: Tomcat 6? Really? This is not a Servlet 3.1 container, so your whole web.xml would not work in first place. Supplying Servlet 3.1 via webapp in Maven makes no sense. The servletcontainer itself is responsible for that. Upgrade to Tomcat 8, which is a Servlet 3.1 container. Start here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: @BalusC That's the thing I did not even expect to be a problem. Thanks, works great. I took that form mikyong examples, did not think even on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BalusC said in comment.
Problem was in tomcat 6. Had to upgrade to newer version of tomcat - 8. 
Many kudos.